# Selected single card view and change color

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have list card. When click in my menu show three options. Second options set card as default card. This card set border card in green. When click another card select this card border in green. How make if you select another card as default card, unselect previous card which was default and change default color.

[image]

this my adapter with show settiing 
        public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
        boolean isSelected;
        private Card card;
        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<Card> cardslist = new ArrayList<>();
        private MySharedPreference mySharedPreference;

        public CardAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Card> cardslist) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.cardslist = cardslist;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }


        @Override
        public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_cardview, parent, false);
            return new CardViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final CardViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            card = cardslist.get(position);
            mySharedPreference = new MySharedPreference();
            holder.nameCard.setText(card.getNameCard());
            holder.setDate.setText(card.getCreateDate());
            holder.expirationDate.setText(card.getExpirationDate());
            holder.menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, holder.menu);
                    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.cardmenu);
                    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

 case R.id.defaultCard:
//this option set card as defult 
                                holder.cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_card_shodow);
                                Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(mContext, "Podana karta została ustawiona jako domyślna.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) toast2.getView();
                                if (layout.getChildCount() > 0) {
                                    TextView tv = (TextView) layout.getChildAt(0);
                                    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                                }
                                toast2.show();

                                break;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put an extra boolean variable in card model. and can add a check in onbindViewHolder like this:

```
*if(card.booleanIsTrue())
{
put green color
}
else
{
put other color
}*

you can set it to true or false onClick like this:

*if(card.booleanIsTrue())
{
put other color
card.setbooleanFalse;
}
else
{
put green color
card.setbooleanTrue;
}
notifyDataSetChanged();*
```

Comment: For my case i need to create a adapter for multiple selection and i am using same approach there ....it works ..

Answer (score 0):

I would try try one:

1. Instead of isSelected make int selectedPos and public and give it like -1 value so it makes it not a valid position.
2. Modify code like this:

   ```
   @Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   if (selectedPos == position) {
       return 1;

   return 2;       
   } 

   @Override
   public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         Context context = parent.getContext();
         LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

         View view;
         if (viewType == 1) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.selected_layout, parent, false);
            return new CardViewHolder(view);
         }
         else {    
           view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.default_layout, parent, false);
           return new CardViewHolder(view);    
         } 

   }


   public void onBindViewHolder(final CardViewHolder holder, final int position) {
      card = cardslist.get(position);
      mySharedPreference = new MySharedPreference();
      holder.nameCard.setText(card.getNameCard());
      holder.setDate.setText(card.getCreateDate());
      holder.expirationDate.setText(card.getExpirationDate());
      holder.menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

           final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, holder.menu);
           popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.cardmenu);
           popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                case R.id.defaultCard:
                //this option set card as defult 
                selectedPos = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

           break;
        ...
   ```
3. Make R.layout.default_layout and R.layout.selected_layout depending on your layout needs like above you showed.